# is there any way to block read when reached end of file util there is new data write to file in java

Tags: java, file

I have 2 java processes, process A writes data to file, process B reads data from file. Sometimes process A is not running, process B needs to read existing data from file,so I cannot use socket instead of file.

The problem is, when B reach to end of file, read function returns immediately,if I retry without `sleep()`, CPU usage is 100% even if there is no new data. If I try with `sleep()`, response time and performance is not good.

Is there any way to block read when reached end of file until there is new data written to file, as if I was using socket?

Comment: One thread reading a file should not cause 100% CPU usage, it sounds like you have other issues. However, you could use a shorter sleep time that is a balance between response speed and cpu usage, maybe 100ms instead of 1 second (1000ms)?

Comment: This is already a bad design. You should be using a socket or some other form of IPC, or a database, or a JMS system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WatchService API of java.nio package. In this, you can create watcher for any modifications in the directory. There will different events for different modifications based on which you can trigger the read.